# Limit of a Cosh function

Tags: calculus, limits, hyperbolic-functions

Evaluate
$$\lim_{t\to\infty} (\cosh x)^{1/x}.$$ I tried to use L'Hopital's but I think I made a mess of the differentiation, and the differentiation doesn't seem like it'll help much.

Comment: $\cosh x = \frac{\mathrm{e}^x + \mathrm{e}^{-x}}{2}$

Answer (score 5):

Note that for positive $x$ we have 
$$\cosh x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}\lt \frac{e^x+e^x}{2}=e^x.$$
Also, 
$$\cosh x\gt \frac{e^x}{2}.$$
Thus
$$(1/2)^{1/x}e \lt (\cosh x)^{1/x}\lt e.$$
Since $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1/2)^{1/x}=1$, by squeezing the desired limit is $e$.

**Added:** In a comment, OP has asked whether one can solve this using L'Hospital's Rule. so here goes.

Note that $\ln((\cosh x)^{1/x})=\frac{\ln(\cosh x)}{x}$. The numerator an denominator both blow up, and are differentiable, so we can use L'Hospital's Rule. We get
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(\cosh x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}}{1}.$$
For the limit on the right, after some cancellation we can rewrite $\\frac{\sinh x}{\cosh x}$ as
$$\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{e^x+e^{-x}}.$$
Divide top and bottom by $e^x$. So we want
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1-e^{-2x}}{1+e^{-2x}}.$$
The limit is $1$.

Since the $\ln$ function is continuous, and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\ln((\cosh x)^{1/x})=1$, it follows that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (\cosh x)^{1/x}=e^1=e$.

Comment: I think you mean $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1/2)^{1/x}=1$.

Comment: Many thanks for spotting it!

Comment: Sure!${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Can this question also be solved using LH rule? If yes, how?

Comment: I will write it up. It is I think less informative.

Comment: I skipped the part of the question that said using LH rule, or otherwise. Thanks for your effort. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. In my opinion, the L'Hospital's Rule method is messier, and further away from the basic intuition that for large $x$ the function $\cosh x$ is extremely close to $\frac{e^x}{2}$.